# Database deadlock blocking

Tags: database, blocking, database-deadlocks

Is database deadlock mostly caused by Database blocking? In other words is blocking inherent reason for deadlock? Does multiple blocking of resources a necessary condition for deadlock? If blocking is prevented in Databases does that mean we can avoid Database Deadlocks?

Have checked different resources from Internet and got conflicting answers:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/TransactionGettingStarted/blocking_deadlocks.html

From the above resource the answer is indicative of the below excerpt

> A deadlock occurs when two or more threads of control are blocked,
>   each waiting on a resource held by the other thread. When this
>   happens, there is no possibility of the threads ever making forward
>   progress unless some outside agent takes action to break the deadlock.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/BSM/SC32-9084-00/en_US/HTML/bsmd240.htm

From the above resource the answer is indicative of the below excerpt

> Blocking is different than a deadlock. Deadlocking is a condition that
>   occurs when two users or sessions have locks on separate objects and
>   each process is trying to acquire a lock on the object that the other
>   process has. The SQL server automatically detects and resolves
>   deadlocks. If a deadlock is encountered, one of the processes is
>   terminated, allowing the other process to continue.

Comment: Is your question a theoretical one? or a real-world problem? if a real world, it would be better if you provide the error / problem you are seeing and not quote documentation. In most cases its TABLE locking and not Database, but a database lock may occur if the database is undergoing backup/restore/migration/etc

Comment: @nrathaus It is a real world problem that occurred in our database servers. Where my colleague and myself had an altercation today where I asked him to check for DB blocking in Server and he said that there is deadlock and not DB blocking as observed. I said one leads to another ....

Comment: How did you get to the conclusion that locking occurred? i.e. what did you see? please paste here your observation and not the user guide

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the two snippets as conflicting. Both specific it's because of each of two (or more) process/thread has a resource the other one needs.

Blocking and deadlock are not the same, but deadlock does happens due to blocking - but only  because each of two processes block each others request for resources.

So - a deadlock is happening due to blocking, but blocking does not automatically cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Consider read/write inconsistency as a disease, blocking as the medicine for that disease and deadlock as a side effect of the medicine.